# My laptop doesn't charge after plug back the charger AC

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management, laptop, battery-charging-threshold

After last update 22.04.2 LTS (3 days ago), i found my laptop doesn't reconzise, when I plug back the charger (AC no USB-C). I realize if you restart/shut down or suspend you laptop with the charger is pluged in, Ubuntu reconize and charging the laptop. But in operational state after disconect and plug it back, doesn't charge.

I would like to know if an issue on the update or it's a simply configuration shall I change to fix this issue?

Comment: What packages were updated? Review the list of updated packages located at `/var/log/apt/history.log`